# CouchDB Errors: "undefined symbol: js_fgets" on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, ubuntu-10.04

ServerFault Community.

I have been wrestling with this problem for weeks without resolution and was hoping that someone here might be able to help.  As indicated above, this is in Ubuntu 10.04 (x86) using CouchDB 0.11.0.

I have build and installed CouchDB 0.11.0 from source.  Everything with the dependencies and with the CouchDB install itself 'goes off without a hitch' - no errors or complaints in the configure, make or install...

CouchDB seems to be running 'fine'.  I can access Futon without issue and utilize all CouchDB functionality found in Futon... Unfortunately, when I attempt to use any shows/views for an installed Couch App, I get the above js_fgets error before terminal (and the Couch log) fills up with TONS of JSON.  Nothing ever renders in the browser, though Firebugs reports.

I have used the official instructions (paying special attention to the 10.04 instructions) and have followed pretty much every Google thread that I can find on similar issues.  I have chase SpiderMonkey (and Rhino) as well as Erlang as the culprit, but despite reinstalls and tests with these components, I still cannot get past this CouchDB issue on my system...

Ideas?  Pointers?  Suggestions?  Has anyone successfully installed and used CouchDB 0.11.0 on an Ubuntu 10.04 system to RUN APPLICATIONS? I have come across multiple individuals who immediately respond 'yes, I have it installed - it works great' only to have them realize in the end (as I did) that just because Futon thinks things are working, doesn't mean CouchDB is properly handling ALL requests.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.  I get a error with js_fgets, but mine is during compile time.  I filed a ticket.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-826